# Cannot understand this part from the textbook

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm reading the book Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems by Gerald Teschl. Or rather, I am reading the online edition: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/index.html

On page 15 it says:

> More generally, consider the differential equation $$ \dot{x} =
>  f\left(\frac{ax + bt + c}{\alpha x + \beta t + \gamma}\right). $$ Two
>   cases can occur. If $a \beta - \alpha b = 0$, our differential
>   equation is of the form $$\dot{x} = \widetilde{f}(ax +bt) $$

I understand the rest of the page. But this step makes no sense to me. Would someone care to explain to me what the author might mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\beta = \frac{\alpha b}{a}$

plug in to get

$\dot{x} = f\left(\frac{a x + bt + c}{\alpha x + \alpha b/a t + \gamma}\right) = f\left(\frac{a x + bt + c}{\alpha/a( a x + b t + a\gamma/\alpha)}\right)$

which is a function of $ax + bt$.

Comment: Thank you, that seems correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $a\beta - \alpha b$ is a determinant, and in the special case $c=\gamma=0$ you can always write the argument of $f$ in a $ax+bt$ form (because the numerator is a multiple of the denominator). In general, if the numerator is a multiple of the denominator, you could do a change of coordinates and resort the argument to a $ax+bt$ form, but seems to me that the condition $a\beta -\alpha b=0$ is necessary but not sufficient.